# android browser intent back button in android?

Tags: android, android-intent, back-button-control

I am new to android. I am using browser using Intent.its working fine but am facing problem when i click on back button on device app exits. How to go to previous app when clicking on back button?

Comment: am using code this one     Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("https://play.google.com"));
  startActivity(intent);

Comment: make sure you are not finish your activity.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
 @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        super.onBackPressed();
    Intent signup_intent = new Intent(ActivityB.this, ActivityA.class);
    startActivity(signup_intent);
    }
```

//onClick of Back button in ActivityB put this it will take you to ActivityA

Comment: Are you finishing your ActivityA while going to ActivityB.

Comment: i had gave finish() also but not working..give me any suggetion